# Want to convert NSDateFormatter with suffixes to a NSdate

Tags: nsdateformatter

I have a string with date 1st Junuary 2012 or 22nd September 2011 or 3rd July 2011 or 14th October 2011. I need to convert this date with nd,st,th and rd suffixes to a specific date i.e dd-mm-yyyy. Can anyone guide me with this. What is the dateformatter for this kind of dates (22nd July 2011). Any help will be great.

Comment: I have updated my answer in your other question to add this as an example. Check it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13116110/converting-mutliple-date-format-into-a-single-format-in-iphone/13118199#13118199