# Want NSDateformatter for January,2000 or January 2000

Tags: objective-c, nsdateformatter

I have a date January 2012. I need a `NSDateFormatter` for such date.

Here's my code...

```
//Array of Date-formatter Strings
NSArray *dateFormatterList = [
    NSArray arrayWithObjects:
        @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", 
        @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ",
        @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'",
        @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
        @"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", @"MM/dd/yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'",
        @"MM/dd/yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", @"MM/dd/yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS",
        @"MM/dd/yyyy'T'HH:mm:ssZ", @"MM/dd/yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss",
        @"yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss", @"yyyyMMdd", @"dd-MM-yyyy",
        @"dd/MM/yyyy", @"yyyy-MM-dd", @"yyyy/MM/dd",
        @"dd MMMM yyyy", @"MMddyyyy", @"MM/dd/yyyy", 
        @"MM-dd-yyyy",@"d'st' MMMM yyyy",
        @"d'nd' MMMM yyyy", @"d'rd' MMMM yyyy",
        @"d'th' MMMM yyyy", @"d'st' MMM yyyy",
        @"d'nd' MMM yyyy", @"d'rd' MMM yyyy",
        @"d'th' MMM yyyy", @"d'st' MMMM",
        @"d'nd' MMMM", @"d'rd' MMMM",
        @"d'th' MMMM", @"d'st' MMM",
        @"d'nd' MMM", @"d'rd' MMM",
        @"d'th' MMM",@"MMMM yyyy",nil];

NSString *targetDateFormatString  = @"dd-MM-yyyy";

count++; 

if (resultString) {
    for (NSString *dateFormatterString in dateFormatterList) {
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:dateFormatterString];
        NSDate *originalDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:resultString];

        if (originalDate) {
            [dateFormatter setDateFormat:targetDateFormatString];
            myDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:originalDate];
            [finalDateArray addObject:myDateString];
            //NSLog(@"Converted date String is %@", myDateString);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try something yourself?

Comment: yeah i did try MMMM yyyy. but its not working.

Comment: Update your question with the exact code you tried, and the string that failed to parse.

Comment: @user1448493, I just now tried with the code and both "MMMM yyyy" and "MMMM, yyyy" are working for me. Do you want to change to "MMMM yyyy" or change from that to targetDateFormatString?

Comment: i need to change January 2000 to dd-mm-yyyy.

Comment: @user1448493, In the above code set resultString = @"January 2000" and try again. I am getting it as "01-01-2000". I have updated my other answer to your question to make it as a method. Use that method and call it as, [self dateStringFromString:@"January 2000" destinationFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"]. Please note that since date param is not present in your original string, you will see 01 as the default date.

Comment: @user1448493, Did this help you? or are you still facing issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For January, 2000

try,

```
@"MMMM, yyyy"
```

and For January 2000

try

```
@"MMMM yyyy"
```

I have updated my answer to your other questions with this as well, Please check [my answer in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13118199/1730272)

**Update:**

In the above code in question set `resultString = @"January 2000"` and try again. I am getting it as `"01-01-2000"`. I have updated my other answer to your question to make it as a method. Use that method and call it as, `[self dateStringFromString:@"January 2000" destinationFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"]`. Please note that since date param is not present in your original string, you will see `01` as the default date.