# NSDateFormatter dateFromString working on iOS 10 but returning nil on iOS 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

My in house app which is working for last 2 years have `messages dates` in different format

```
1* Sep 20, 2017 at 8:09:39 PM

2* Feb 3, 2017, 5:49:42 PM
```

I am converting these string to date like this

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[df setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[df setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[df setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
return [df dateFromString:dtStr];
```

For date 1 its working perfectly on iOS 10 and 11

but for date 2 its only working on iOS 10 not on iOS 11

How can i fix this?

Comment: Expecting a vague format like NSDateFormatterMediumStyle to work like this is really lazy and risky. If you know the format of the date strings, why don't you use a formatter with a _specific_ format that matches it?

Comment: @matt agreed, but it is interesting that that code works in iOS 10 but not 11. I wonder if Apple has changed the default date or time format between those OS versions? Seems likely.

Comment: @DuncanC Maybe they have, but the code was silly to start with; it worked more or less accidentally.

Comment: problem is multiple people has already worked on this project, fixing date to one formate is not going to work now(its a fix later thing), because the messages that are already stored in db have different date formats... I need to fix this issue to release a hot fix......

Comment: @S.J You misunderstand. Your fix is to replace the use of the `dateStyle` and `timeStyle` with the use of `dateFormat`. You will have to try each of the possible formats that can be sent to your app.

Comment: @matt Please tell me why using NSDateFormatterMediumStyle is bad, its provided by apple.

Comment: "its provided by apple” but not for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems your bigger issue is actually that you have multiple date formats coming in.

See this question/answer here:
[Converting mutliple date format into a single format in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13116110/converting-mutliple-date-format-into-a-single-format-in-iphone)

It doesn't seem to be that efficient ... but it would work for you. It also utilizes using specific dateformats as others have commented.

Here's an adapted answer specific to your question:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    NSString *date1 = @"Sep 20, 2017 at 8:09:39 PM";
    NSString *date2 = @"Feb 3, 2017, 5:49:42 PM";

    NSLog(@"Date 1: %@", [self dateFromString:date1]);
    NSLog(@"Date 2: %@", [self dateFromString:date2]);
}

- (NSDate *)dateFromString:(NSString *)dateString {
    NSDate *date = nil;

    // here, insert other date formats you know might be given
    NSArray *dateFormatterList = @[
                                   @"MMM d, y, hh:mm:ss a",
                                   @"MMM d, y 'at' hh:mm:ss a"
                                   ];

    if (dateString) {
        for (NSString *dateFormatterString in dateFormatterList) {
            [self.dateFormatter setDateFormat:dateFormatterString];
            date = [self.dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
            if (date) break;
        }
    }

    return date;
}

- (NSDateFormatter *)dateFormatter {
    if (!_dateFormatter) {
        _dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    }
    return _dateFormatter;
}
@end
```

Basically what is happening is ... we have an array of known date formats. We iterate through each format and attempt to get an NSDate from the date string using that format. If we get one, we return that date. If you have more date formats, just insert it into the dateFormatterList. You'll notice I already put in two dateformats: `@"MMM d, y, hh:mm:ss a"` for date 1* and @"MMM d, y 'at' hh:mm:ss a" for date 2* above.

I tested it with your two dates and it works.
Logs:

`Date 1: Wed Sep 20 20:09:39 2017`

`Date 2: Fri Feb  3 17:49:42 2017`

Answer (score 1):

Please check :

```
var dateStr = "Feb 3, 2017, 5:49:42 PM"

NSDataDetector *detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeDate error:&error];
NSArray *matches = [detector matchesInString: dateStr options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [dateStr length])];

for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
    if (match.resultType == NSTextCheckingTypeDate) {
        NSLog(@"%@", match.date);
    }
}
```

**Swift 4**

```
var date = try? NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.date.rawValue)
                .matches(in: dateStr, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: dateStr.count))
                .flatMap{$0.date}
print(date!)
```